# Python (Flask/SQLAlchemy) throwing NameError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, nameerror

Here are the two classes I've defined.

```
class Day(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'day'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(9), nullable = False)    
    #Foreign Keys
    function_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Function.id))
    schedule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Schedule.id)) #Python wont recognize this for some reason...

class Schedule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False, primary_key = True)
    #Foreign Keys
    assigned_employee = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Employee.id))    
    #Relationships
    days = db.relationship('Schedule', backref = 'day', lazy = True)
```

I'm using python in the command prompt to check the code and it seems to not recognize the Schedule class right below it.

> ### Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "models.py", line 1, in  from main import db
>   File "Not\The\Actual\Path.py", line 9, in  from views import *
>   File "Not\The\Actual\Path.py", line 2, in  from models import *
>   File "Not\The\Actual\Path.py", line 48, in  class Day(db.Model):
>   File "Not\The\Actual\Path.py", line 57, in Day schedule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Schedule.id)) #Python wont recognize this for some reason...
>    NameError: name 'Schedule' is not defined

It's perfectly fine with the 'function_id' line, but angry about the one right below it.

Comment: If your classes are defined in that order, it's because the interpreter hasn't gotten to class Schedule yet since it comes after class Day. Order matters in Python

Comment: I am ashamed. I knew c++ was like that, but not python. I thought that since it was a higher level language it wouldn't matter. I guess it makes sense since it's interpreted line-by-line. Every line would by a command in the cli, in a sense.